# How do I open the SearchView programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

There is this widget for the ActionBar which called 'SearchView'.
When it's not in use, it looks like this:

[image]

And when it's in use, it looks like this:

[image]

I want (programmatically of course) to open the searchview (make it "in use").

I tried several functions such as:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    searchView.performClick();
    searchView.requestFocus();
```

But none of those worked...

The SearchView in the XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:title="Search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Expand the `SearchView` with

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

and collapse it with

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

You need to change the value of `android:showAsAction` from `ifRoom|collapseActionView` to `always`. The `SearchView`'s attribute `android:iconifiedByDefault` should be `true`, which is the default value, otherwise the user can not collapse the `SearchView` after it was expanded programmatically.

Comment: Hello, a keyboard pops-up but the SearchView does not open.

Comment: OK, I'm a little surprised, works for me. `searchView.onActionViewExpanded()` should work as well. If not, can you show your menu.xml?

Comment: Hello, this also didn't work. I updated the post with the XML source code.

Comment: i have one query, how to show the caret besides the app icon when the `searchView` expands and hide the caret when `searchView` collapses?

Comment: I tried opening the searchView again during `onResume()` with the provided method, which was too early. The OptionMenu Items did not settle at that time. Using `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` worked perfectly for me.

Comment: showAsAction="always" will display an ugly fullscreen search bar though, after rotation

Comment: `showAsAction="always"` makes the search icon stay on the action bar when is expanded, which doesn't resemble to appearance when focusing the search manually.

Comment: Don't use this and use the solution provided in @qbait's answer (`searchMenuItem.expandActionView()`). Setting `showAsAction="always"` causes several problems (as commented above).

Answer (score 82):

Try to call `expandActionView()` on MenuItem, not onActionViewExpanded() on ActionView.

It works for me.

```
MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
```

Comment: Works perfect, but only for API > 14. For earlier API you can use this: MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);

Comment: This is the correct solution - The selected one forces you to set `showAsAction: always` which causes some issues.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use support library only when necessary, do this

```
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (Utils.hasIceCreamSandwich())
        searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
    else MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);
```

else simply do this

```
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem);
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is late but

Try calling expandActionView() to open it and collapseActionView() to close it. You can call requestFocus() on the actual Action View via getActionView() to give the search view focus :)

Answer (score 6):

For `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`,

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true)   // didn't work

searchMenuItem.expandActionView()  // didn't work

MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchMenuItem) // didn't work

searchView.onActionViewExpanded()  // didn't work
```

The following worked for me,

```
searchView.findViewById<View>(R.id.search_button).performClick()
```

Comment: You should rather use `searchView.setIconified(false)` to expand the search view

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the answer of Matthias Robberts:

I wanted a list fragment to keep it's search value and set it after user returns from other fragment.

```
if (myViewModel.filterTextSaved.isNotEmpty()) { // Kotlin, storing state in ViewModel
    searchItem.expandActionView() // needs to come first, otherwise empty text
    theTextArea.setText(courseViewModel.filterTextOnClick)
}
```

and for the menu I keep `always|collapseActionView`, otherwise it stays open when user deletes the text.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution to expand SearchView programmatically
because I need to restore expand state. No one solution was worked for me.
Except using Handler().post(). I know it's not a good practice to use post().
But I'm working on legacy project and this workaround is acceptable for me.

Initialize variables block

```
val searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search_item)
val searchView = searchMenuItem.actionView as SearchView
```

How to expand SearchView:

```
Handler().post {
   searchMenuItem.expandActionView()
}
```

Reason why post() helps:
if your app is not well written it may doing too much work on UI thread.
post() ensures that your block of code will be executed when UI thread will be available for execution. Which means if you are using this workaround you can notice small delay between SearchView expanding

Answer (score 0):

To open up a `searchView` keeping the `close_button` in the end use this in `onCreate`:-

```
searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_button).performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **[Material Search View](https://m3.material.io/components/search/overview)** `com.google.android.material.search.SearchView`,

you can show and hide the `` with

```
searchView.show() // expands SearchView

searchView.hide() // collapses SearchView
```