# Android SearchView with custom ActionBar

Tags: android

I want to create search view with custom action bar same as to search view in Action-bar. I don't know how to do this.I surfing on the net but most of the result will show the search view with Action-bar not custom Action-bar.But i want to add Search view on my custom Action Bar.Can someone help me .

Here is my custom Action Bar code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_post);
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        dbhelper = new MyDbHelper(this);
        dbhelper.onOpen(db);

        Intent intent = new Intent(CustomActionActivity.this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);

        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

        ImageView imgSearchBtn = (ImageView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imgSearchButton);
        imgSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Click on ", " Searchview !!!! ");

            }
        });

        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);

    }
```

I want to call search view on button click with collapse and expand function.

```
ImageView imgSearchBtn = (ImageView)mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.imgSearchButton);
        imgSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Click on ", " Searchview !!!! ");

            }
        });
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use `Toolbar` as your custom `ActionBar` (Note, that you have to use NoActionBar style in your styles.xml and add `Toolbar` manually to your layout) You still can use menu inflater:

search_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Just `setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);` where mToolbar is your `Toolbar`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    if (searchView != null) {
        // do something with it
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I cant understand what are you saying ? I want to call searchview on click on this button imgSearchBtn

Comment: So just keep reference to it and call setIconified, according to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14235987/4142087

Comment: You can add SearchView to your layout (custom_actionbar.xml) or do it programmatically, later use findViewById(R.id.your_search_view_id) and do with reference whatever you want

Comment: But how to apply collaps and expand functinality

Comment: @p.ld I gave you link to the answered question. Simply call mSearchView.setIconified(false); to expand and mSearchView.setIconified(true); to collapse

Comment: Thanks its  works without mSearchView.setIconified(true); and call mSearchView.setIconified(false);

Comment: It's just a way to expand and collapse programmatically in your onClick listener